# R - Dplyr - How to add a calculated field based on current data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, group-summaries

I'm grouping a data frame by the column "month", and then summarising the "users" column.

Using this code:

```
Count_Users_By_Month <- Users_By_Month %>% group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(Users = length(unique(users)))
```

I get this, that i'm 100% sure it's correct:

```
     month       Users
1 Diciembre      4916
2 Noviembre      3527
```

**Question 1: How to add a column showing the variation in "Diciembre" based on "Noviembre"?(In percentage %).**

**Need to create a colum for the variation month to month**

The formula (pseudocode) is this one:

```
(DiciembreUsers-NoviembreUsers)/NoviembreUsers
```

** Of course the value for Noviembre would be clear cause there is no data from previous month (October).

I tried this code to do this, but get an error:

```
Count_Users_By_Month <- Users_By_Month %>% group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(Users = length(unique(users))) %>%
  mutate(Variacion = (Count_Users_By_Month[1,2]-Count_Users_By_Month[2,2])/Count_Users_By_Month[2,2])
```

**Error: not compatible with STRSXP**

**Last edit:

Problem solved, Thanks @Khasha. See comments:

**Changed "lag" for "lead".... it worked. Just added "lead" to the divison part to get the formula right.**

```
mutate(variation=(Users-lead(Users))/lead(Users))
```

Comment: `mutate(variation=(Users-lag(Users))/Users)`

Comment: @akrun The dataset is the first one, it just shows the users for "Diciembre" and  "Noviembre". I need to show also the Variation from Diciembre to Noviembre.

Comment: If your data.frame is reversed (row-wise), does it work correctly? (Referring to a just-deleted comment where you said @Khashaa's results show in Nov and should show in Dec.)

Comment: `arrange` your data chronically, or use `lead` instead of `lag`

Comment: @r2evans No, i changed it row-wise in Excel and the result should be: -0.28. But Khashaa is -0.39

Comment: @Khashaa works with lead, instead of lag. I'll investigate the difference between those two. Problem solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the original data frame:

```
    month       Users
1 Diciembre      4916
2 Noviembre      3527
```

This is the answer:

```
Count_Users_By_Month <- Users_By_Month %>% group_by(month) %>% 
                        summarise(Users = length(unique(users))) %>%
                        mutate(variation=(Users-lead(Users))/lead(Users))
```

**Need to investigate how "lead" works. All the credits to @Khashaa, see his answer in comments. 
Just modified the formula, added "lead" in the division part to get the right answer**